# Pandas :Record count inserted by Python TO_SQL funtion

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I am using Python `to_sql` function to insert data in a database table from Pandas dataframe.

I am able to insert data in database table but I want to know in my code how many records are inserted . 
How to know record count of inserts ( i do not want to write one more query to access database table to get record count)?

Also, is there a way to see logs for this function execution. like what were the queries executed etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, since python cannot know how many of the records being inserted were already in the table.

Comment: why does it have to know that ? I am using a simple insert, and looking for something similar to SQL%Rowcount function in oracle where I get how many rows were affected by my query.

Comment: @Ummed because if you are inserting 17 rows, and 12 were already in the table, it only inserted 5. Any function with a % in Oracle is (obviously) not standard SQL.

Comment: if I add if_exists='append', it will insert all records irrespective of 'if a similar record exists in database table or not'.

Comment: @Ummed That makes no sense. You cannot duplicate primary keys, for example.